# Force user to use https:// + www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, https

The target is the subdomain tc.gamingprouk.net and it is using valid SSL. I want .htaccess to add not only https:// or www., I want both of them! Like https://www.tc.gamingprouk.net.
This is what my `.htaccess` contains:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tc.gamingprouk.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tc.gamingprouk.net/$1 [R,L]
# Hiding file extensions
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# For .php, .html & .shtml URL's:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.shtml [NC,L]
```

Here is the problem:

**Case 1:**

User navigates to -> `tc.gamingprouk.net`
.htaccess rewrites to -> `https://tc.gamingprouk.net`
The problem: There is no `www`.!

**Case 2:**
User navigates to -> `www.tc.gamingprouk.net`
.htaccess does nothing!
The problem: It is without `https`!

**Case 3:**
User navigates to -> `https://www.tc.gamingprouk.net`
.htaccess rewrites to the same
The problem: Only in this case it is with both `https://` and `www`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answered

I found out what you can Use. The following **.htaccess** code is part of google's:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
# Hiding file extensions
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# For .php, .html & .shtml URL's:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.shtml [NC,L]
```

Comment: If you have {SERVER_NAME} and if you try going directly with www. before the **SUBDOMAIN** it will add www. twice, which won't work due to an invalid subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This checks to see if both `www` and `HTTPs` are on, if they're not, it will turn them on. Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Not working if you visit the website via http://www.tc.gamingprouk.net/ - it doesn't adds https! Like in **Case 2**

Comment: All but http:// www .tc.gamingprouk.net redirect to https:// www. tc.gamingprouk.net. http:// www .tc.gamingprouk.net redirects to http:// www .www. tc.gamingprouk.net which is an invalid domain. To fix this, use `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]` instead of the last line.